UIImage does not release memory
The code below is to reproduce what I encountered.
After loading and cleaning data, the memory is still not freed.
And the weirdest thing is that if I press the clean data twice, the memory could be released. How does the UIImage work?
I tried using UIImage(contentsOf:) and UIImage(data:), and they gave me the same result.
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
struct MainView:View {
    @State var data:[Data] = []
    @State var urls:[URL] = []
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("clean data"){
                data.removeAll()
                urls.removeAll()
            }
            Button("load data"){
                loadData()
            }
            HStack{
                ForEach(urls, id: \.self) { url in
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(contentsOfFile: url.path)!)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                }
            }
        }
    }
        func loadData(){
            for i in 0...5{
                urls.append(Bundle.main.url(forResource: "output\(Int.random(in: 0...2))", withExtension: "png")!)
            }
        }
    
}



Is MainView being released?

@trojanfoe No, MainView is the root view

Try using AsyncImage since you are using URL

In body you should only init structs and UIImage is an object so that is the cause of your memory leak. To fix, you'll need to init the object in some action like your loadData and hang on to it then supply it to Image.
Fortunately you can avoid this by simply using a different Image constructor: Image(name _:bundle:) which internally probably loads the UIImage once at the right time for you and probably releases it at the right time too.
